# Bold text in prefab info in inspector - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, prefab

While modifying a prefab, I got this

[image: Prefab with overrides]

How to change the **Position**, **Rotation** and **Audioclip** Text to normal?

Comment: Why is this an issue in the first place? ^^ It is an explicit UI feature telling you these values have been modified and light not be equal to the ones in the prefab anymore .. nothing to worry too much about ^^

Comment: I'm not worried at all, it's just I wanted to know why that happened and I wrote a quick and easy answer for others who want the same. Period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a Prefab and move it to the scene (or leave it after creating it in the scene). If you change the value in prefab, the text will become bold. But if you just change the field to the old value, the text will remain bold.
To reset the value in prefab, use the right mouse button -> Revert. When the value is reset, the text will be normal.

Answer (score 0):

**AudioClip** word is set to normal with Overrides option.
**Rotation** and **Scale** words can be set to normal text with right click on the word and choose *Apply to prefab* or *Revert*

Answer (score 0):

When you chane a property of a prefab in a scene, Unity highlights them in inspector panel. When you apply or revert this changes,Unity doesn't highlight. If you click `Overrides` button in top right side you can see options.

Comment: You're right, but the Transform changes keep in bold even when clicking on overrides... Did you mean top right side?

Comment: Yes,yes.top right side. Sorry, it's my fault.